# Best approach to hide certain user information on rails using devise as the method for authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Currently I'm creating a rails app for understanding the framework right now my controller authenticates the user, I have three types of user using enum and a field called row in the users table and on my application controller I have this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception

 protected

  def authenticate_editor!
   redirect_to request.referrer, :flash => { :error => "You don't have 
   the permissions to do this!" } unless user_signed_in? && 
   current_user.editor?
  end

  def authenticate_admin!
   redirect_to request.referrer, :flash => { :error => "You don't have 
   the permissions to do this!" } unless user_signed_in? && 
   current_user.admin?
 end
end
```

So right now on my controllers, I defined a before action for those protected methods, for example the admin role is the only one who can't destroy posts in my posts_controller. That works but on my view any user can see the **destroy action link** on the index page of that model, if a regular user clicks that link, the flash appears and he's unable to complete the action but I don't want regular users to see the link if is useless to them, I know I can hide it for example using this:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
   <%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post),
   method: :delete,
   data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
<% end %>
```

But I want to know if this is the correct approach, should I continue using conditional for those links to actions or if there's a better way?

Comment: A slight change you could make is to do a single-line conditional:
 `<%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } if current_user.admin?` %>

Comment: I guess it mostly depends of what you want to do, you want to show the same view for every user? if that's your case I think those conditionals should be enough, but if you want to scope everything depending on the role, you can use routing and even different layouts, that mean more views but you won't have a lot of conditional in your views.